# x64 NASM Assembler: Binary Search

Tags: beginner, windows, assembly, binary-search

While quarantine I decided to look into the assembly language, as it's quite interesting to see how code works on the lower levels. To challenge myself I made a binary search algorithm. The OS is Windows.
I just code casually (in Python and C++, so I know about the concept of pointers), therefore I don't have *that* much experience.

I just wanted to put this on code review to know if this code style is acceptable or if I'm disregarding important conventions. So please critique and let me know.

```
bits 64

section .text
    global main
    extern printf
    extern ExitProcess
    
main:
    mov r12, list       ; load list into register
    mov r13, len >> 3   ; r13 holds the width of the search "sector"
    test r13, 1         ; test if the first search "sector" is even
    jz is_even          ; if not, it's set to an even number
    inc r13
    is_even:
    push r13            ; save width
    shl r13, 2          ; multiply index by 4 to get the width in bytes
    add r12, r13        ; move the pointer to the first search position
    pop r13             ; restore width
    
search:
    shr r13, 1          ; halve search "sector"
    push r13
    shl r13, 2          ; get width in bytes
    
    mov r14d, dword [r12]     
    cmp r14d, dword [target] ;compare target to current search position
    je finish           
    jl search_right     
    jg search_left
    
search_left:
    sub r12, r13   ; move search position
    pop r13
    jmp search
search_right:
    add r12, r13   ; move search position
    pop r13
    jmp search

finish:
    lea rcx, [fmt]  ; set printf format
    mov rdx, r12    ; rdx is pointer to the target
    sub rdx, list   ; we want the index of the target, so we SUB the pointer to the first element
    shr rdx, 2      ; ints are 4-byte, so we have to devide the difference by 4
    
    sub rsp, 40     ; shadow space
    call printf
    add rsp, 40
    
    mov rax, 0
    call ExitProcess
    

section .data
    fmt db "%d", 10, 0     ; printf format string
    target dd 123          ; number we're looking for
    list dd 4, 123 ,2584, 4510, 8451, 6987, 12543
    len equ $ - list
```

Comment: Have you compared this to the disassembled output of a roughly-equivalent C compilation?

Comment: yeah, but it took me some time. basically, it's very similar to my manual asm code, but the if/else flow is at first unintuitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code style

Your code style is certainly acceptable - everyone is entitled to their own coding habits.
To further improve readability, and readability is key, I would change the following:

- put all labels in the same separate column. You didn't do this for *is_even*, *fmt*, *target*, *list*, and *len*.
- don't just have 1 space character between the instruction/directive and its operand(s). Start all operands in their own column.
- beware of redundant comments like 'mov r12, list  ; load list into register'
- don't add redundant tags like `dword` in `mov r14d, dword [r12]`. The register name `r14d` already states this is a dword.
- avoid using ambiguous terminology. I found it odd to read about *sectors* and *widths*. In case of binary searching, many people will prefer to talk about *array partitions* and *number of elements*.

### The code has multiple issues

You seem to be confident that a match will always be found. No provision is made for a failure!

The comment on `mov rdx, r12  ; rdx is pointer to the target` is wrong. What you've got is a pointer to the matching array element.

The array *list* holds dword-sized elements. In `mov r13, len >> 3`, you only need to shift twice to get the *number of elements*.

In the top part of the program you first add an imaginary element to the array, then you make `r12` point to behind it, and later your code also happily reads from these non-existing elements. Analyzing beyond this point becomes futile.

I think having recognized an attempt to write a *uniform binary search*. Although I didn't use that particular approach, you might find it interesting to read [a post of mine that shows 2 ways to binary search an array](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105165/variations-on-binary-searching-an-ordered-list). I know it was written for 16-bit, but that should not stop you from stealing from it...